# Adding dynamic views on Android

Tags: android, view

I have the following code:

```
scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
...
public void addItem(String str, int id) {
    LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(this);
    lay.setId(id);

    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setText(str);

    lay.addView(txt);
    scroll.addView(lay);    
}
```

And when i call addItem() once it's Okay, but when i call it twice or more, like this:

```
addItem("text1",1);
addItem("text2",2);
```

my app crashes :(

Comment: show us the exception stack trace...it might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `ScrollView` can only host 1 direct child.

You could create a `LinearLayout` as the only child of the `ScrollView`, and then add to the `LinearLayout` instead of the `ScrollView` in your `addItem` method.

```
scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
LinearLayout lay = new LinearLayout(this);
scroll.addView(lay); 
// maybe do some more with lay here, or define it in xml instead of adding it here in the code
...
public void addItem(String str, int id) {
    LinearLayout lay2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    lay2.setId(id);

    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    txt.setText(str);

    lay2.addView(txt);
    lay.addView(lay2);    
}
```

Comment: @eightx2 what is the need of lay2 in addItem method can't i directly add view to the lay...like lay.addView(txt);  instead of adding text to a layout and then adding that layout the actual layout??

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Yes that's right, you can do that. I just edited his code directly, that's the only reason `lay2` is there.